# RegEx for 4 characters and 7 numbers. No special characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write RegEx to match some strings like ABCD1234567, 123ABC456D7 or 12A34B56C7D. There should be 4 characters and 7 digits, order is not important. And there shouldn't be any special characters like *.,- etc.

I already tried to write something like this.

`^[A-Zaz]{4}[0-9]{7}$`

Can someone help me?

Comment: In the context of which programming language?

Comment: Oracle Apex, PLSQL. Actually I need to warn user if the text is not in this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `^[A-Zaz]{4}[0-9]{7}$` matches 4 times A-Za-z and 7 digits in that order.

You could use lookaround assertions with quantifiers instead:

```
^(?=(?:[^A-Za-z\r\n]*[A-Za-z]){4})(?=(?:[^0-9\r\n]*[0-9]){7})[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=(?:[^A-Za-z\r\n]*[A-Za-z]){4})` Assert 4 chars A-Z
- `(?=(?:[^0-9\r\n]*[0-9]){7})` Assert 7 digits
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed or use `[A-Za-z0-9]{11}` to match exactly 11
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0hDyB1/1)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for the allowed characters and exact length and match the rest.

```
^(?=[A-Za-z\d]{11}$)\d*(?:\D\d*){4}$
```

- `(?=[A-Za-z\d]{11}$)` the lookahead checks for exactly 11 `[A-Za-z\d]`
- `\d*(?:\D\d*){4}` matches exactly 4 digits with any `\D` *non digits* in between

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6is502/2)